# JSONB Querying array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have the following a column in a PostgreSQL table that has a JSONB field with data like:

```
[{"id":33,"url":"","name":"test"}, {"id":45,"url":"","name":"test"}]
```

I'm trying to query it and return the element that matches the id. I have the following query in Rails, but it doesn't seem to be matching:

Book.where('data @> ?', '[{"id": 33}]')

Comment: What is the expected returned result of the query?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean, I want it to return the array element that matches based on the id being equal to 33. So, it should return `{"id":33,"url":"","name":"test"}`

Comment: does the answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need some elements in the jsonb array, you will need to transform those into records and cross join them with their parents:

```
Book.joins(", jsonb_array_elements(books.data) obj")
    .where("obj->>'id' = '33'")
    .select("obj")
```